# PHP Framework: Ebay Like Site

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp, codeigniter, frameworks

I am going to be builiding a site like ebay - with all the features of ebay. Please note my payment method is limited to paypal.

> What would be the best PHP framework
>   to use to build this quickly,
>   efficiently and with the smallest
>   learning curve?

I have narrowed down to **CodeIgniter** as the major contender for this project - but having looked through the docs I couldn't find a library or class that I can use with paypal - is the same for all frameworks- surley not?

**Zend** framework - I considered this but although its documentation is very good, hardly any video tutorials - other frameworks seem to have lots of these especially with normal developers creating screencasts - where is the Zend community!

**CakePHP** - Having read the stackoverflow threads, I gathered this is a slow framework, giving  developers little control as it seems to be a CMS backbone rather than a framework - agree? It was also said cakePHP and Zend have a steeper learning curve than CodeIgnitor.

I have start my short-listing again and I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks all

Comment: CodeIgniter is probably the most often misspelled / mispronounced framework name ever. Everyone and their sister has their own way of pronouncing and writing it.

Comment: It sounds like you can just skip building the site and use eBay directly

Comment: markojs site says: "Marko is powering high-traffic websites like ebay.com", so it is a hint that markojs can be used to build sites like ebay, albeit not related to PHP, so can't be an anser to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll very likely find CodeIgniter to have the lowest learning curve.  Regardless of the framework you choose, you'll have to pick up where the framework leaves off, and that is going to mean a significant amount of work on your part (if you truly want to implement all the features of ebay).  There seems to be a [PayPal lib in the CodeIgniter Wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib/).  Looks like it would be a great place to start.

Comment: Of the options you listed, Codeigniter easily has the strongest documentation, which is why it's so easy to learn/use. I'd highly recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

Cake is not a CMS backbone, it's a framework like the others. It's just more opinionated, i.e. geared towards CRUD operations (create, read, update, delete, what you typically do in a CMS). If your application is focused on CRUD, Cake will give your development a kickstart; you can get a complete admin interface for your database tables up in, literally, minutes.

Thanks to that it may be a little slower, especially compared to "loose" frameworks like Zend, but in the end it won't matter much. You can do anything with any of these frameworks and any of these frameworks can be optimized to run as fast as possible. Try to get a simple prototype app up and running in all of them and choose the one that seems most comfortable to you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd really recommend Codeigniter for speed. I've made a few things with it and it was great.

If you need some help learning Codeigniter Nettuts has been doing some [really good screencasts](http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/)

Comment: Does it have a paypal class/library?

Comment: Paypal has NVP and SOAP API's, so you don't need a specific library to make use of them.  Check out www.x.com (I have no idea how Paypal managed to get that domain name...) for code and tutorials on using the PayPal API with PHP.

Comment: @Ryan The Youtube/Google API I think is rest based but the Zend framework still have developed a library for this.

Comment: I really liked watching those screencasts.  Thanks for this suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, it won't matter.  Your code for database and presentation will trump any 'problems' your framework has.  The frameworks you listed are awefully similar. You'll be more or less stuck with which you pick, so pick one and learn all you can.

If you're going with codeigniter (note, maybe take a look at Kohana too, the php5 fork of CI), you can always use libs out of Zend if theres something that fits your needs.